# phpMyAdmin - This table does not contain a unique column while it does

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Everytime I try to edit a value of any table it will give the following error:

> This table does not contain a unique column. Features related to the
>   grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete links may not work after
>   saving.

The problem is that I do have primary keys set, even when I export a dump from another machine where it does work, and import in my local machine, it will give the same error when trying to update values, while all the indexes and primary keys are set correctly.

Some information on phpMyAdmin and my local webserver:

**Database server**

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.10 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

**Web server**

```
Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/5.5.31 OpenSSL/0.9.8zg
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
PHP version: 5.5.31
```

**phpMyAdmin**

```
Version information: 4.5.3.1, latest stable version: 4.5.5.1
```

Comment: If you use the phpMyAdmin copy feature (from the Operations tab) to copy that table to a new name or another database, are you still unable to edit?